# What methods can I use to achieve this shaping of the x-axis?

Tags: highcharts

I would like to make a graph like
[this](https://codepen.io/Ivancoppen/pen/ZExPygV?editors=0010):
[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62IsF.png)

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    width: 780
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
    pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
      '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
    footerFormat: '</table>',
    shared: true,
    useHTML: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      pointPadding: 0.1,
      groupPadding: 0.1,
      pointWodth: 20
    },
    column: {
      borderRadius: '2px'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    color: 'orange',
    name: 'Приход',
    data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

  }, {
    color: 'blue',
    name: 'Расход',
    data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

  }]
});
```

But I don't know how I can plot the X-axis like in the screenshot, I would appreciate your help, thanks)

Comment: Please share the screenshot.

Comment: Attached the links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1. You can set the categories in the x-axis. If you put a comma after the last category description, it automatically creates the pattern.

Step 2. Set the tickwidth to 1 in the x-axis.

```
 xAxis: {
    categories: ["0", "1", "2",],
    tickWidth: 1
  },
```

Comment: For certain circumstances, I use this method https://jsfiddle.net/r1d6tozq/29/
How can I center the columns between the ticks as in the screenshot above?

Answer (score 0):

For the second requirement (https://jsfiddle.net/r1d6tozq/29/), add `pointPlacement: 'between'` to the `plotOptions` as follows:

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
      shadow: false,
      pointPlacement: 'between'
    }
  }
```